# How to see twitter trends from the twitter app once an account has been used to login?

Tags: apps, twitter

1. Install the twitter app. (at version 1.3.0.0 on 4th June 2012)
2. Launch the app. 
   -There will be sections called ***top tweets, trends, suggested and nearby*** if you swipe horizontally.
   -Below the app, there will be the the 'sign in' and 'sign up' buttons.
3. Sign in.
4. The timeline loads.
   -There will be other sections called mentions, messages and lists if swiped horizontally.
   -There will be more options available from the ellipsis `...` section of the app.

But I find no option to go back to the sections showing ***top tweets, trends, suggested and nearby***. I know there's a way to return to the sections that were available before I signed in because twice, although erroneously, a particular swipe (or could've been a tap) took me back to these sections when I was in my timeline.

Does anyone know how to return to the ***top tweets, trends, suggested and nearby*** sections once an account has been used to sign in to the twitter app?

Comment: Good question. I tried to find too but I can't.

Comment: I used to think it wasn't possible, but after I managed to do it twice, I know it can be done.

Comment: Boo, not available in my marketplace *yet*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This messed with me a bit too. Once you have logged in you need to press the "search" button on the application bar to get to those options again. Now you can swipe around to navigate **top tweets, trends, suggested and nearby**

Comment: Whoa! To think it was that simple.

Comment: What a awesome anwser!!! Very hidden feature.